# Не могу настроить htaccess на субдиректорию

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache, yii

Здравствуйте, есть проект на yii framework, в нем есть папка, в которой лежит отдельный проект со своим репозиторием. При заходе на project.local/folder все ок и я попадаю на субдиректорию с проектом, когда перехожу на project.local/folder/search, к примеру, все, попадаю на основной проект, htaccess пробовал конфигурировать по разному, но ничего не выходит, правила прилагаю

```
RewriteEngine on
ErrorDocument 404 /error404.html

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
#The following line is enough for .js and .css
AddOutputFilter DEFLATE js css

#The following line also enables compression by file content type, for         the following list of Content-Type:s
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml application/xml

#The following lines are to avoid bugs with some browsers
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css|xml|gz)$">
Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
<ifmodule mod_expires.c>
<Filesmatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf|ico|woff|mp3)$">
ExpiresActive on
ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 weeks"
</Filesmatch>
</ifmodule>

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !rdf [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)(/)$ $1 [L,R=301]

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !\.(png|jpe?g|gif|jpeg|bmp|js|css)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d #commented cuz rdf/ dosen`t wor

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Должно ж вроде как работать, но не хочет...

```
RewriteRule ^folder/(.*)$ /folder/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Заранее спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0):

В .htaccess основного проекта добавьте исключение для папки **/folder**, чтобы index.php не вызывался.

Если в вопросе у вас показан .htaccess от основного проекта, то сделайте так:

```
# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !\.(png|jpe?g|gif|jpeg|bmp|js|css)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d #commented cuz rdf/ dosen`t wor

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```